# Error: Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none

Tags: javascript, enzyme

I got a problem that I cannot figure out what it is related to.
as a matter of fact there are a similar questions asked here in Stockoverflow, but did not help.
I cannot understand how to fix and why it requires enzyme-adapter-react-15 when I am suing react 16.2
i am getting the following error:

```
     FAIL  src\components\Card.test.js (7.032s)    
Expect to render Card component

          Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none.
          To configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })`
          before using any of Enzyme's top level APIs, where `Adapter` is the adapter
          corresponding to the library currently being tested. For example:

          import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';

          To find out more about this, see https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html


      at validateAdapter (node_modules/enzyme/build/validateAdapter.js:16:11)
      at getAdapter (node_modules/enzyme/build/getAdapter.js:27:36)
      at makeShallowOptions (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:357:45)
      at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:408:19)
      at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/build/shallow.js:21:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Card.test.js:8:30)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

the Card.js is as follows

```
    import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount, render } from "enzyme";

const Card = ({ name, email, id }) => {
  return (
    <div className="bg-light-green">
      // some working code
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

the Card.test.js is as follows

```
 import { shallow } from "enzyme";
    import React from "react";
    import Card from "./Card";
    
    //console.log(shallow(<Card />));
    
    it("Expect to render Card component", () => {
      expect(shallow(<Card />).length).toEqual(1);
    });
```

the test file as follows

```
import React from "react";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { shallow, configure } from "enzyme";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

all files are in the same src/component folder

additionally, this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "robofriends",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://some working link",
  "dependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "tachyons": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're configuring enzyme directly in your Card.test.js file ?

Comment: thanks for comment, it is pasted here wrong, I will fix it right now

Comment: Do you have a jest config file ?

Comment: not, I dont have

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your enzyme configuration file somewhere.

For jest, you can add this to your package.json

```
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>pathToYourEnzymeConfig.js"]
}
```

Or use jest config file to do the same thing
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration

Comment: it generates this error:   ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: environment.dispose is not a function

      at node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/runTest.js:102:17
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5401#issuecomment-364581176 Maybe try this ?

Comment: thanks, something is getting more complicated... I got to do a few step beck and then start again...